# BIOS always show on startup of computer and asks to set date and time. How to prevent it?

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop, bios

I have ASUS x550Jk and my BIOS is American Megatrends 303 2175.I15X550.007 F02S080001, which is the latest version of BIOS for my laptop.

Since yesterday when I start my laptop it automatically goes to BIOS and asks to set date and time. Date and time that BIOS shows is the current date and time, so if I just exit from BIOS my laptop boot up just fine; but when I choose 'save and exit', it automatically loads BIOS, not my windows.

I found that the problem might be my CMOS battery but laptop is only half year old. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I would try replacing the CMOS battery first. It's quick, cheap, easy, and very likely to fix the problem.

Comment: Agree with David, its likely just a bad cell. The laptop may only be 6 months old but the battery may have been in stock for years, and the laptop itself could have sat for another while before you bought it.

Comment: Dirty contacts (e.g. fingerprints and skin oils on the battery) will increase electrical resistance, reduce the voltage, and make the battery appear weak.